# Use of JsonIgnoreProperties specific property deserialize properties exists only in JSON

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization

I stumbled upon some code that adds [JsonIgnoreProperties](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) to a property that doesn't exists in class, but exists in `JSON`, e.g.:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"ignoreprop"})
public class VO {
   public String prop;
}
```

When `JSON` is

```
{ "prop":"1", "ignoreprop":"9999"}
```

I wonder if ignoring properties has any advantage(s) performance-wise or is it just redundant code?

> Annotation that can be used to either suppress serialization of properties (during serialization), or ignore processing of JSON properties read (during deserialization).

**EDIT**

Is there an advantage(s) ignoring specific property over all (with
`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if ignoring properties has any advantage

Yes, it is used a lot for forward-compatibility in services. Let's say you have Services A and B. Currently A sends requests to B with some JSON objects.
Now you want to support a new property in the JSON. If you have this feature you are able to let A start sending the new property before B knows how to handle it. **Decoupling** the development processes of those two services.

> ignoring **specific** property over all

This case does have some minor performance advantages. First, it doesn't try to parse this property which can be a simple string or complex object/array. Second, it helps you avoid handling an exception. Think that all the following can be valid calls and you only care about `prop`:

```
{ "prop":"1", "ignoreprop":"9999"}

{ "prop":"1", "ignoreprop":{ "a": { "key": "value", "foo": false }}}

{ "prop":"1", "ignoreprop":[1,2,3,4,5,6..... 1000000]}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage(s) ignoring specific property over all (with 
`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`)?

Comment: @user7294900 - edited to answer your specific question

Comment: So `ignoreUnknown` will try to parse inside `ignoreprop` although it's not a property in class?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, mainly the purpose of use this is **To ignore any unknown properties in JSON input without exception:** which is better not to popup exception when properties are not found either in class or JSON, and this might helps serializing faster [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html)

> Example:
>
> // to prevent specified fields from being serialized or deserialized
>
> // (i.e. not include in JSON output; or being set even if they were included)
>    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "internalId", "secretKey" })
>
> // To ignore any unknown properties in JSON input without exception:
>    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
>
> Starting with 2.0, this annotation can be applied both to classes and to properties. If used for both, actual set will be union of all ignorals: that is, you can only add properties to ignore, not remove or override. So you can not remove properties to ignore using per-property annotation.

Comment: Can you add link to doc? If I want to ignore dozen of properties is it still better?

Comment: yes you can add all of them in annotation or simply add this `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` i will recommend `unknown=true` in case of multiple properties

Comment: Is there an advantage(s) ignoring specific property over all (with 
`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`)?

Comment: lets get this straight, you get JSON with 100 fields, and you only need 5 fields, then is it recommended to set  `ignoreUnknown=true)` or specify each field?, it complete depends on requirement, and this annotation completely avoids exception with unknown fields that is main intention of this  @user7294900

Comment: I just want to know if there's a real reason/advantage to ignore specific property when `ignoreUnknown=true` should cover it (and will be flexible)

Comment: I don't think this will be more perfomance issue until unless json is bigger like 50 or 100 fields, one more if you know the specifi property to ignore and rest of them you need, but you don't know exact contract, then preferef ignoring soecific property